# Are 32-bit libraries installable on Ubuntu 16.04 for Android development?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 but I am stuck because the distribution can not install the 32-bit libraries `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`.

My output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.18) but it is not installable
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a way to solve this issue or I should just revert to 15.04?

Comment: You may be better served asking this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). While your need for an answer is because of a development tool (Android Studio, I presume), the question is really about Ubuntu and packages, and Ask Ubuntu is far better able to answer that sort of question. That being said, try dropping the `lib32stdc++6` part, then try firing up Android Studio again, and see if `mksdcard` is now happy. The mix of packages needed for `mksdcard` sometimes changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add support for 32-bit packages first:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then you have to install the specific 32-bit version of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
```